# Java 8 lambda weak reference

Tags: java, lambda, garbage-collection, java-8, weak-references

I create an object called `Foo`. When I create a lambda or method reference called `Action`, the `Action` object holds a reference to `Foo`.
I pass the action to another class. But if I hold it as a weak reference, it gets gc immediately, because no one stores another reference to `Action`.
But if i hold it as a strong reference, the `Foo` can't be gc, because `Action` holds a referene to it.
So memory leaks happen and I want to prevent it.

My question is: how can I hold a reference to `Action` without preventing gc of `Foo`.

Example:

```
Interface Action {
    void invoke();
}

Class Foo() {
    public void someMethod() {
        ....
    }
}

Class Holder() {
     WeakRefrence<Object> foo;
     public Action action;

     void register(Object source, Action a) {
         foo = new WeakReference(source);
         ??? how can i hold the action without prevent source to gc able.
     }
}


main() {
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Action action = foo::someMethod;

    holder.register(foo,action);
    action = null;
    System.gc();
    //only the holder store reference to action.
    //if i store in holder as weak reference i cannot invoke it any more cause it get gc.

    //foo = null;
    //System.gc();
    //if i grab action in holder as strong refrence the foo cant be gc cause action hold refernce to it.

    holder.action.invoke();
}
```

Comment: Remove this System.gc();

Comment: I can't understand this question. If `foo` has been garbage collected, `action` can never be invoked, since it refers to an instance method of `foo`. Keeping action around but letting foo be gc'd is like saying, "I'd like to keep an ArrayList but let all its items be garbage collected." It defeats the purpose.

Comment: I want to create something like WeakAction in c#.

Answer (score 4):

You have to separate the *action* from the weakly referenced *target*. You should always keep in mind that lambdas are intended to specify *behavior* only.

```
class Foo {
    public void someMethod() {
       System.out.println("Foo.someMethod called");
       // ....
    }
}

class Holder<T> extends WeakReference<T> {
    private final Consumer<T> action;
    Holder(Consumer<T> action, T target) {
        super(target);
        this.action=action;
    }
    public void performAction() {
        T t=get();
        if(t!=null) action.accept(t);
        else System.out.println("target collected");
    }
}

class Test {
  public static void main(String... arg) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Holder<Foo> holder = new Holder<>(Foo::someMethod, foo);
    System.gc(); // we are still referencing foo
    holder.performAction();
    foo = null;
    System.gc(); // now we have no reference to foo
    holder.performAction();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and didn't work. The action still reference to foo. Maybe i  do something wrong?

Comment: It worked when I tested it. Maybe you just ran into the fact that `System.gc()` is only a hint. Further, it won’t work when debugging it as the debugger will hold references to the objects it has seen. You may use a profiling tool like `JVisualVM` to create and inspect a heap dump.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse strategy would be to register all Actions to the Foo. That seems not to fit.

Why not [SoftReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)? Then the Action has to check, but that is what seems to be your intention.

You could additionally register the Action at the foo (addListener, inverse strategy), to signal a change of state to "dying."

Comment: If i hold the action with softreference it eventually get gc when java run out of the memory but i want to hold a reference to action until the source is in memory(has hard reference to it). 

"You could additionally register the Action at the foo (addListener, inverse strategy), to signal a change of state to "dying."
Its create a circular reference Foo holds the Action and Action  holds the Foo so neither of them can be gc but maybe i misunderstood what you suggest.

Comment: No, you had it correct about circular refering; normally one would do one thing, like there is a class to keep weak listeners. I am not sure on all ins and outs, but if you can say in Foo, when it going to be freed, one may clean up all its listeners and send them a message to set their Foo to null. I am afraid only you may find the adequate solution. I do not know of any magic class, even though April the first is tempting to tell otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: how can I hold a reference to Action without preventing gc of Foo.

I'd say that a few things need to be clarified first:

- Should `action` know on which `Foo` instance it should be invoked? I assume so, otherwise it'd be simple.
- Should `action` prevent its stored `foo` from GC? I assume no, as this is what you're asking.
- Should the `foo` prevent its action from GC? I assume yes, as it'd be too strange.

So you can have no strong reference from `action` to `foo`. This means no lambdas (if I understand them correctly). A strong reference from `foo` to `action` would be OK, but you don't seem to want to store them there.

I guess, it's doable, albeit a bit complicated:

- In `action` store a `WeakReference<Foo>`.
- Don't use `SoftReference` unless you want to keep `foo` as long as possible.
- Before doing anything with `foo`, check if `get` returned `null`.
- Run some cleanup in the `holder` to get rid of `Actions` having lost their `Foo`s (`ReferenceQueue` is your friend).

Comment: "Run some cleanup in the holder" -> then why not just use a WeakHashmap in the holder? I understand that the holder doesn't know the foo. So you can't do that.

Comment: @СӏаџԁеМаятіи Assuming I understand the problem correctly, each `action` should life as long as their corresponding `foo` does, but a `WeakHashMap` would lose them immediately (as they're not referenced elsewhere). The cleanup is possibly, by simply iterating over the `action`s and dropping those which have lost their `foo`s. The holder knows all `action`s and asks them if they still refer their `foo`.

Comment: But Action is just an interface. You can't query it for the foo. 
I think only someone who knows WeakAction can answer this.

Comment: @СӏаџԁеМаятіи Sure, if there should be a weak reference in `Action`, you need some concrete implementation of it. With writing simply `Action action = foo::someMethod;` you won't get any weak reference... and maybe it all can't work the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this problem just now. I tried several things and they don't work.

Typically I have a StringHolder that can be assigned a String, with method set() and listen().
I also have a IntReceiver that contains the int it received, with method set(value) and get().

The typical use case is :

```
StringHolder sh= new StringHolder();
IntReceiver ir = new IntReceiver();
sh.listen(str->ir.set(str.length());//should test null
sh.set("123");
assert(ir.get()== 3);
```

And I tried several implementations. They can't work simply. I tried double weak ref, I tried other things I can't even remember.

The only way to work, is to force the receiver to keep a reference to the lambda. So I need a new interface RefStore, with store(Object ref) method, and I make that IntReceiver implement it ; the implementation is just a linkedlist.

Then the listen() needs to take a RefStore as parameter, and store the lambda in the refstore. The usage code becomes

```
sh.listen(str->ir.set(str.length(), ir);
```

And then your  lambda can safely be stored in weak references, to be removed when a new value is set and the ref is null.

Here is my StringHolder

```
public class StringHolder{

    private List<WeakReference<Consumer<String>>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public int listeners() {
        return listeners.size();
    }

    public void listen(Consumer<String> listener, RefStore holder) {
        holder.store(listener);
        listeners.add(new WeakReference<>(listener));
    }

    public void set(String data) {
        for (Iterator<WeakReference<Consumer<String>>> it = listeners.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Consumer<String> call = it.next().get();
            if (call == null) {
                it.remove();
            } else {
                call.accept(data);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is  my IntReceiver

```
public class IntReceiver implements RefStore {

    private int value;

    private transient LinkedList<Object> stored = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public void store(Object o) {
        stored.add(o);
    }

    public void set(int val) {
        value = val;
    }

    public int get() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

Here is the main :

```
public class MainExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntReceiver ir = new IntReceiver();
        StringHolder sr = new StringHolder();
        sr.listen(s -> ir.set(s.length()), ir);

        sr.set("123");
        System.out.println("value for 123 is " + ir.get());
        System.out.println("calls=" + sr.listeners());
        add(sr);
        sr.set("1234");
        System.out.println("value for 1234 is " + ir.get());
        System.out.println("calls=" + sr.listeners());
        GCManage.force();
        sr.set("132");
        System.out.println("value for 132 is " + ir.get());
        System.out.println("calls=" + sr.listeners());

    }

    protected static void add(StringHolder ls) {
        IntReceiver is = new IntReceiver();
        ls.listen(s -> is.set(s.length()), is);
    }

}
```

Here is the force() method to force the GC.

```
public static void force() {
    WeakReference<Object> wr = new WeakReference<>(new Object());
    int nb = 0;
    int arraySize = (int) (Math.min(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 32 / 8, Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5) / 10);
    while (wr.get() != null) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Object[] trash = new Object[arraySize];
        System.gc();
        nb++;
    }
    logger.debug("gc after " + nb + " buffers");
}
```

Here is the output :

```
value for 123 is 3
calls=1
value for 1234 is 4
calls=2
value for 132 is 3
calls=1
```

as you can see, after the call to add() a listener is added but not gc yet ; once forced the GC however it is collected. The issue is that the set() method must be called to check for null refs and remove them.

The main issue is that this way of making it work requires to tweak a lot with classes. Especially a problem if you want to have lambda do things, eg syserr, without storing the data.
It would be better to be able to attach a lambda to an object so that lambda is considered strong referenced .

One more thing I need to try, is to try to work with finalize in a subclass of weakReference, to avoid actually finalizing the ref until another weak reference is actually GC'd.

edit : I added a few more test in the main, by adding to listeners using print, one of them also using the parameter(dynamic) and the other one not using it (static) :

```
public class MainExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntReceiver ir = new IntReceiver();
        StringHolder sr = new StringHolder();
        sr.listen(s -> ir.set(s.length()), ir);

        sr.set("123");
        System.out.println(" value for 123 is " + ir.get());
        System.out.println(" calls=" + sr.listeners());
        System.out.println("adding weak referenced listeners");
        add(sr);
        addSysoDynamic(sr);
        addSysoStatic(sr);
        sr.set("1234");
        System.out.println(" value for 1234 is " + ir.get());
        System.out.println(" calls=" + sr.listeners());
        System.out.println("force GC");
        GCManage.force();
        sr.set("132");
        System.out.println(" value for 132 is " + ir.get());
        System.out.println(" calls=" + sr.listeners());

    }

    protected static void add(StringHolder ls) {
        IntReceiver is = new IntReceiver();
        ls.listen(s -> is.set(s.length()), is);
    }

    protected static void addSysoDynamic(StringHolder ls) {
        ls.listen(s -> System.out.println(" received(dynamic) " + s + " from " + ls.getClass().getSimpleName()), o -> {
        });
    }

    // no ref to the argument means the lambda is static and linked to the class
    protected static void addSysoStatic(StringHolder ls) {
        ls.listen(s -> System.out.println(" received(static) " + s), o -> {
        });
    }

}
```

Here is the result :

```
 value for 123 is 3
 calls=1
adding weak referenced listeners
 received(dynamic) 1234 from StringHolder
 received(static) 1234
 value for 1234 is 4
 calls=4
force GC
 received(static) 132
 value for 132 is 3
 calls=2
```

as you can see, the dynamic listener is GC, but not the static one, since the lambda is static and therefore referenced as long as the class is.